# Iphone : what do I need to do to a nib file to an exisitng object

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have tried using an outlet to connect my tableview controller to my object, setting the nib name in IB and setting the class in IB but it still wont link? I know this as im trying to set my table view to 'grouped'

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what the problem is. Do you have the outlet visible in IB, but it's not letting you draw a little line to the table view? In that case, double check the class of the outlet. It should be the same (or a superclass of) what you're trying to hook up to it.

Comment: Sorry, the title came out wrong it should have said "what do I need to do to a nib file to connect it to an existing object."

The problem is that I have a root view controller that is subclassing UITableView and I want to set it to a 'grouped' style. Usually I would just open the nib and set it that way but in this case there isnt one, so I need to create one and connect it to my RootViewController object.

I have tried going in to IB and setting the class and the nib name and connecting the view property of files owner to the table but it and set the table to grouped but it stil wont change?